# How can I run a MySQL query in PHP and send the data back to the browser?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to export a MySQL database using PHP, I want the data to be saved to the users computer, I want this data to be saved as a .sql file. I am trying to make it as simple as phpmyadmin.

I have tried everything I can find on Google.

I have tried to do mysql dumps, custom scripts, but they all write the data to the server, never the client computer.

All help is appreciated!

Comment: You're using Google wrong. [1](https://code.google.com/p/db-mysqldump/), [2](http://www.downscripts.com/mysqldump-database-backup_php-script.html), [3](http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/210208-mysqldump-on-the-client-side/)

Comment: Just press export, on phpmyadmin and it will by fault save it with `sql` extension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `header()` to set an appropriate content type and output the data.

Normal output is sent to the user as `Content-Type: text/html`

If you want to send output as a text document, use:

```
header('Content-type: text/plain');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="yourfilename.sql"');
echo $your_sql_content;
```

Comment: Thank you, This solves the problem of how I download the file, but I am still researching on how to get the proper sql code from php, I have found one, but it keeps inserting lnbr into the sql code.

Comment: @KevinWeber You should open another question and provide complete details, including your existing code and a specific description of the problem and any error messages.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

header("Content-type: text/plain");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=YOUR_EXPORT.sql");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');

$your_query = mysql_query( "select * from bla bla bla ... ");
while( $codes = mysql_fetch_array( $your_query ) ) {
    $row = array();
    $row[] = some data ... 
    fputs($fp, $row);
}
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: You're absolutely right; I missed that.  I updated my answer.